# Ionide F# not working in VSCode, no debug messages, not in Running Extensions

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code, f#-interactive, ionide

I used Ionide F# a lot in the past for the amazing code completion in F# scripts. I didn't use it in a while and it doesn't work at all. I checked the debug output on level DEBUG or INFO and I only get:

```
[16:00:00 INFO ] .Net runtime specified
[16:00:00 INFO ] finding FSAC for
    runtime: NET
    mono: mono
    dotnet: null
```

Ionide doesn't show up in Running Extensions, and there's also no more other debug output. So it seems the extension crashes, but `Log(Extension Host)` only shows the activation of the service, not that it crashed or any other errors:

```
[2018-11-19 16:00:00.507] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension Ionide.Ionide-fsharp {"startup":false,"activationEvent":"onLanguage:fsharp"}
[2018-11-19 16:00:00.507] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule C:\Users\mcu3si\.vscode\extensions\ionide.ionide-fsharp-3.30.0\fsharp
```

I'm using F# 4.5 on Windows with .NET 4.7.2. VSCode is version 1.29.1 and Ionide is version 3.30.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer and forgot to post it back in the day:

You need to have `dotnet` installed (that is .NET core). IMHO it should show an error message, but in case it still doesn't, that's the reason why.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had issues with Ionide in VSCode and the workaround I used to fix it was to uninstall and reinstall both the extension and vscode.

To me it seems the extension updates has mangled something in the Ionide setup.